# How can i get the same font size and font family in word or open office documents on copying the text from ck editor

Tags: c#, asp.net, fonts, ckeditor

In my application i have ck editor,when user enters something in ck editor and copies that entered text word document or open office documents then the font size is not same as the font size in the ck editor that is if i enter some text with font size 8 in ck editor and when i copy the same text and paste it in word or open office spread sheet documents the the font size is getting varied.can any body help me out as i am new to this

As listed above the font size when we gave some text in ckeditor is in the left side and the font size when we copy the same text from ck editor is in the right side.how can i display the same font size when i copy the text from ck editor to word

```
 <div>
            <CKEditor:CKEditorControl ID="CKEditor1" BasePath="~/ckeditor00/" runat="server" Width="1108px" Height="383px">      

            </CKEditor:CKEditorControl>
        </div>




<script src="jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $(document).ready(function () {
                CKEDITOR.on('instanceReady', function (ev) {
                    ev.editor.dataProcessor.htmlFilter.addRules({
                        elements: {
                            p: function (e) { e.attributes.style = 'font-size:12px; font-family:Times New Roman;'; }

                        }
                    });
                });

                });
            });
    </script>
```

Comment: What are you putting in the clipboard when a user "copy"s in the ck editor?

Comment: sounds like you need to not "just" do things, but you need to get the clipboard object that the "copy" action puts into the OS clipboard, and rewrite it to ensure the correct data is in it for Word to pick up the correct markup